# Axioms needed to prove existence of unordered triplet

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axioms

I know the defenition for ordered triple: just define $\\(a,b)$ to be $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and apply this reasoning to $\\((a,b),c)$. But how about **unordered** triple? 
And what axioms guarantee us that such triple exists?

Comment: How do define an unordered triple? Simply the set $\{a,b, c\}$?

Comment: @PaulFrost well, unordered means order doesn't matter. So $\{a,b,c\} =\{b,a,c\}$ and so on

Comment: That is satisfied if you define it as $\{a,b,c\}$. But let us write $[a,b,c]$ for the  unordered triple. whatever its concrete definition might be. Do you allow that $[a,a,b] = [a,b,b]$ or do you want $[a,a,b] \ne [a,b,b]$ if $a \ne b$? With the set definition it would be =. In order words, do you want to take into account multiplicity?

Comment: @PaulFrost so i need to do something like Kuratowski definition of ordered pair? E.g to express unordered triple using set theory language?

Comment: I think you should specify the *properties* you expect an unordered triple should have and then look for an adequate construction. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_pair.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset.

Answer (score 0):

For [$\mathsf {ZFC}$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) we use Pair axiom and Union axiom:

> $\{ x,y,z \} = \{ x,y \} \cup \{ z \}$.